# Spring + jQuery + FTL: how to handle checkbox value of "on" or null

Tags: jquery, json, spring, checkbox, freemarker

When I serialize my form and use some code to turn the serialized query string into a JSON object, the checkboxes I inserted with:

```
<@spring.formCheckbox path="signUpDto.checkbox_terms" />
```

have "checked" and "unchecked" values of "on" and null respectively. I googled this behavior, and I found it is standard behavior of jQuery form serialization.

In my DTO, my `checkbox_terms` variable is declared like this:

```
private boolean checkbox_terms;
```

However, when I try to post my serialized object form data back to the server, it returns a 400 error (Bad request). It might be because of this wrong data type on `checkbox_terms` as the two values are "on" and null.

So my question is, how should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the `boolean` to string, like so:

```
private String checkbox_terms;
```

and when you need to check if it's checked or not, do

```
[dto].getCheckbox_terms().equalsIgnoreCase("on")
```

for checked or

```
![dto].getCheckbox_terms().equalsIgnoreCase("on")
```

for unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think the problem is from the checkbox ? 
Because 415 error means the Content-Type of POST request is not handle by server, in this case is application/json.

I guess you use Spring MVC. So could you try set consumes="application/json" in the RequestMapping.

Refs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I put in the wrong error message because I got confused by looking at the wrong thing. Your solution did help the 415 error though, so I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Thank you. Finally you got the answer of yourself.